# SQL Server installation failing due to Software Restriction Policy - but no policy exists on server?

Tags: windows, sql-server, group-policy, installation, windows-server-2022

I am attempting to install SQL Server Express 2022 on Windows Server 2022.

When I setup the Windows server, I added a Software Restriction Policy for preventing the installation of executables and msi files. I also added some restrictions to AppLocker.

No matter what I try, when attempting to install SQL Server 2022(or 19), the app constantly fails in two areas.

1. A pop up message appears halfway through saying this:
   *The following error has occured. File <%localpath%>/msoledbsql.msi was rejected by digital signature policy.*
   [image: Error message advising a .msi file was rejected by digital signature policy.]
2. The installation fails later on after continuing briefly with the below message: *This installation is forbidden by system policy. Contact your system administrator.*
   [image: Installation Failure error message advising process is forbidden by system policy.]

It points me to a log file, which I have included below:

```
=== Verbose logging started: 22/01/2024  09:45:45  Build type: SHIP UNICODE 5.00.10011.00  Calling process: C:\ProgramData\Plesk\Installer\SQL2022EXPRADV_x64_ENU\x64\ScenarioEngine.exe ===
MSI (c) (AC:14) [09:45:46:000]: Resetting cached policy values
MSI (c) (AC:14) [09:45:46:000]: Machine policy value 'Debug' is 0
MSI (c) (AC:14) [09:45:46:000]: ******* RunEngine:
           ******* Product: C:\ProgramData\Plesk\Installer\SQL2022EXPRADV_x64_ENU\1033_ENU_LP\x64\setup\SqlSupport.msi
           ******* Action: 
           ******* CommandLine: **********
MSI (c) (AC:14) [09:45:46:001]: Client-side and UI is none or basic: Running entire install on the server.
MSI (c) (AC:14) [09:45:46:002]: Grabbed execution mutex.
MSI (c) (AC:14) [09:45:46:003]: Cloaking enabled.
MSI (c) (AC:14) [09:45:46:003]: Attempting to enable all disabled privileges before calling Install on Server
MSI (c) (AC:14) [09:45:46:003]: Incrementing counter to disable shutdown. Counter after increment: 0
MSI (s) (DC:40) [09:45:46:010]: Running installation inside multi-package transaction C:\ProgramData\Plesk\Installer\SQL2022EXPRADV_x64_ENU\1033_ENU_LP\x64\setup\SqlSupport.msi
MSI (s) (DC:40) [09:45:46:010]: Grabbed execution mutex.
MSI (s) (DC:E0) [09:45:46:012]: Resetting cached policy values
MSI (s) (DC:E0) [09:45:46:012]: Machine policy value 'Debug' is 0
MSI (s) (DC:E0) [09:45:46:012]: ******* RunEngine:
           ******* Product: C:\ProgramData\Plesk\Installer\SQL2022EXPRADV_x64_ENU\1033_ENU_LP\x64\setup\SqlSupport.msi
           ******* Action: 
           ******* CommandLine: **********
MSI (s) (DC:E0) [09:45:46:012]: Machine policy value 'DisableUserInstalls' is 0
MSI (s) (DC:E0) [09:45:46:055]: Note: 1: 2203 2: C:\Windows\Installer\inprogressinstallinfo.ipi 3: -2147287038 
MSI (s) (DC:E0) [09:45:46:057]: SRSetRestorePoint skipped for this transaction.
MSI (s) (DC:E0) [09:45:46:061]: File will have security applied from OpCode.
MSI (s) (DC:E0) [09:45:46:087]: SOFTWARE RESTRICTION POLICY: Verifying package --> 'C:\ProgramData\Plesk\Installer\SQL2022EXPRADV_x64_ENU\1033_ENU_LP\x64\setup\SqlSupport.msi' against software restriction policy
MSI (s) (DC:E0) [09:45:46:087]: SOFTWARE RESTRICTION POLICY: C:\ProgramData\Plesk\Installer\SQL2022EXPRADV_x64_ENU\1033_ENU_LP\x64\setup\SqlSupport.msi has a digital signature
MSI (s) (DC:E0) [09:45:46:261]: Incrementing counter to disable shutdown. Counter after increment: 0
MSI (s) (DC:E0) [09:45:46:262]: Decrementing counter to disable shutdown. If counter >= 0, shutdown will be denied.  Counter after decrement: -1
MSI (s) (DC:E0) [09:45:46:263]: SOFTWARE RESTRICTION POLICY: C:\ProgramData\Plesk\Installer\SQL2022EXPRADV_x64_ENU\1033_ENU_LP\x64\setup\SqlSupport.msi is not permitted to run at the 'unrestricted' authorization level.
MSI (s) (DC:E0) [09:45:46:263]: The installation of C:\ProgramData\Plesk\Installer\SQL2022EXPRADV_x64_ENU\1033_ENU_LP\x64\setup\SqlSupport.msi is not permitted by software restriction policy. The Windows Installer only allows installation of unrestricted items. The authorization level returned by software restriction policy was 0x0 (status return 0x0).

MSI (s) (DC:E0) [09:45:46:263]: Note: 1: 1718 2: C:\Windows\Installer\de178b1.msi 
MSI (s) (DC:E0) [09:45:46:266]: MainEngineThread is returning 1625
MSI (s) (DC:40) [09:45:46:266]: No System Restore sequence number for this installation.
MSI (s) (DC:40) [09:45:46:267]: User policy value 'DisableRollback' is 0
MSI (s) (DC:40) [09:45:46:268]: Machine policy value 'DisableRollback' is 0
MSI (s) (DC:40) [09:45:46:268]: Incrementing counter to disable shutdown. Counter after increment: 0
MSI (s) (DC:40) [09:45:46:268]: Note: 1: 1402 2: HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Installer\Rollback\Scripts 3: 2 
MSI (s) (DC:40) [09:45:46:268]: Note: 1: 1402 2: HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Installer\Rollback\Scripts 3: 2 
MSI (s) (DC:40) [09:45:46:268]: Decrementing counter to disable shutdown. If counter >= 0, shutdown will be denied.  Counter after decrement: -1
MSI (c) (AC:14) [09:45:46:270]: Decrementing counter to disable shutdown. If counter >= 0, shutdown will be denied.  Counter after decrement: -1
MSI (c) (AC:14) [09:45:46:270]: MainEngineThread is returning 1625
=== Verbose logging stopped: 22/01/2024  09:45:46 ===
```

As you can see, the log tends to point the failure towards this section:

```
MSI (s) (DC:E0) [09:45:46:263]: SOFTWARE RESTRICTION POLICY: C:\ProgramData\Plesk\Installer\SQL2022EXPRADV_x64_ENU\1033_ENU_LP\x64\setup\SqlSupport.msi is not permitted to run at the 'unrestricted' authorization level.
MSI (s) (DC:E0) [09:45:46:263]: The installation of C:\ProgramData\Plesk\Installer\SQL2022EXPRADV_x64_ENU\1033_ENU_LP\x64\setup\SqlSupport.msi is not permitted by software restriction policy. The Windows Installer only allows installation of unrestricted items. The authorization level returned by software restriction policy was 0x0 (status return 0x0).
```

I have tried various different approaches to this. I am currently logged on as the local Administrator root account, running the installer as Administrator etc. I have deleted **all** Software Restriction Policies and the registry folder for it. I have also removed everything from AppLocker. I have also checked the Run for Users and not Local Admin account checkbox in Software Restrictions (although now empty) and rebooted and refreshed GPO, but whatever I try, this simply will not work.

What am I missing here? Is there something in GPO that is causing this failure to report incorrectly? Or is there a bug in Windows Server 2022 potentially not recognising I have removed the Software Restriction Policies?

Just to add, incase it's the issue, server is connected to Azure Arc.

Any help greatly appreciated.

Comment: Does it fail if the Application Identity service is stopped and disabled? That's the simple way to shut off AppLocker.

Comment: Hi @GregAskew - thanks for the comment. I have just disabled and stopped Application Identity Service and unfortunately, it still occurs.

Answer (score 0):

I have actually discovered the issue. Unfortunately, the wording of the error message is completely incorrect and signposts the user on a wild goose chase. Can't imagine anyone else will find themselves in this unique set of circumstances, but just in case, here's the solution!

My GPO was set to never let the Administrator accounts lockout, but server antivirus/maintenance software could override that if a severe network attack attempt is detected. This meant the account would still be able to be logged in to despite being locked out, but would prevent any administrative actions taking place on the account.

This can be resolved by checking that GPO and antivirus policies do not compete, and importantly, going to `lmgrusr.msc` and unlocking any locked out accounts.